# How to deploy flask with socketio to heroku and have it upgrade to websockets

Tags: flask, gevent, flask-socketio, eventlet, gevent-socketio

Locally, it works. Socketio upgrades to websocket instead of resorting to polling.

This is obvious from the logs:

```
...
FYnWEW0ufWGO7ExdAAAA: Received request to upgrade to websocket
FYnWEW0ufWGO7ExdAAAA: Upgrade to websocket successful
...
```

---

Upon deploying the application, it **partially works** when I create a `procfile` with the content:

> `web: gunicorn app:app`

The issue here is that socketio fails to upgrade to websocket and therefore resorts to polling.

[Here is a gif showcasing that it in production doesn't upgrade to websockets and resorts to spamming pollings instead](https://i.gyazo.com/78b066360b19c92c91cd7c6f85b7901e.mp4)

---

My file structure is

```
wsgi.py
app.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
```

---

This is how I initialize socketio

```
app = ...
socketio = SocketIO(app,
    logger=True,
    engineio_logger=True,
    cors_allowed_origins="*"
)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, debug=False, port=5000)
```

Notice Im not setting `async_mode`, [which was the issue for this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51350162/7123519)

---

How do I deploy my flask app with socketio to Heroku and have it upgrade to websockets?

I think the issue is that Im just not using the right procfile command to start the application in deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a procfile with the content

`web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 wsgi:app`

Did the job.

---

Also, it is important that your dyno is set to "ON" [image]

Comment: I've had some issues with sockets before. It completely took over my dyno and blocked HTTP requests. What does --worker-class do, and does it not make your website really slow?

Comment: @odinchess I am not sure, but I haven't had any issues with it. By the way, this is where I learnt about command: https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#gunicorn-web-server

Comment: It seems to work with flask-sse too now! Thanks for the help. I used the second command (e.g. gevent instead of eventlet). Do you get H12 or H15 errors for server timeout?

Comment: @odinchess Nope, no errors.

Comment: I had 1 worker just like yours and it was not enough to handle my incoming traffic. How did you scale when you have heavy track to your application?